# How to click-through a div without losing its hover events?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have 2 divs stacked upon one another. I want to be able to receive click events for the bottom element without losing hover events for the top element.

If I assign pointer-events: none top the top element, the click-through works, but then I lose the hover events for the top element.

How can it be done?

Comment: would explain morer if you share some code, or img.

Comment: A Short, Self Contained, Correct (Compilable), Example would be helpful (http://sscce.org/)

Answer (score 1):

The MDN docs clearly says that's what is supposed to happen:

> **none**
>    
>   The element is never the target of mouse events; however, mouse events
>   may target its descendant elements if those descendants have
>   pointer-events set to some other value. In these circumstances, mouse
>   events will trigger event listeners on this parent element as
>   appropriate on their way to/from the descendant during the event
>   capture/bubble phases.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/pointer-events

What you can do is write a jQuery script that captures the clicks and transmits them.

```
jQuery("top-div").click(function(e)
  {
     e.preventDefault();
     jQuery("bottom-div").click();
  });
```

Something like that...